# VB.Net MasterPage Page.PreLoad Property not found

Tags: c#, vb.net, cookies, csrf, master-pages

I am trying to implement Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) using Microsoft .Net ViewStateUserKey and Double Submit Cookie. For more please visit this [link](https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/developer-guide-csrf)

The above code is in C# and i am converting this into VB.Net. Now The problem is that in this code there is a line

```
Page.PreLoad += master_Page_PreLoad;
```

When i try to convert the same line in VB.Net it does not find any such event `Page.PreLoad`

Please help how can i do this.

Thanks

Comment: Was this solved? Having the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

The C# MasterPage template converted to VB looks like this:

```
Partial Class MasterPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

    Private Const AntiXsrfTokenKey As String = "__AntiXsrfToken"
    Private Const AntiXsrfUserNameKey As String = "__AntiXsrfUserName"
    Private _antiXsrfTokenValue As String

    Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim requestCookie = Request.Cookies(AntiXsrfTokenKey)
        Dim requestCookieGuidValue As Guid

        If requestCookie IsNot Nothing AndAlso Guid.TryParse(requestCookie.Value, requestCookieGuidValue) Then
            _antiXsrfTokenValue = requestCookie.Value
            Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue
        Else
            _antiXsrfTokenValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
            Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue
            Dim responseCookie = New HttpCookie(AntiXsrfTokenKey) With {
                .HttpOnly = True,
                .Value = _antiXsrfTokenValue
            }

            If FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL AndAlso Request.IsSecureConnection Then
                responseCookie.Secure = True
            End If

            Response.Cookies.[Set](responseCookie)
        End If

        AddHandler Page.PreLoad, AddressOf master_Page_PreLoad
    End Sub

    Protected Sub master_Page_PreLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            ViewState(AntiXsrfTokenKey) = Page.ViewStateUserKey
            ViewState(AntiXsrfUserNameKey) = If(Context.User.Identity.Name, String.Empty)
        Else

            If CStr(ViewState(AntiXsrfTokenKey)) <> _antiXsrfTokenValue OrElse CStr(ViewState(AntiXsrfUserNameKey)) <> (If(Context.User.Identity.Name, String.Empty)) Then
                Throw New InvalidOperationException("Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I believe the specific line you're looking for is `AddHandler Page.PreLoad, AddressOf master_Page_PreLoad`.

For future reference, if you're looking to convert C# code to VB, or vice versa, there is a pretty great Telerik tool for that which can be found here: http://converter.telerik.com/. In order to get the code I posted above, I simply ran the C# template through there.

Answer (score 0):

You can straight away create the method,

```
Private Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ViewState(AntiXsrfTokenKey) = Page.ViewStateUserKey
        ViewState(AntiXsrfUserNameKey) = If(Context.User.Identity.Name, String.Empty)
    Else

        If CStr(ViewState(AntiXsrfTokenKey)) <> _antiXsrfTokenValue OrElse CStr(ViewState(AntiXsrfUserNameKey)) <> (If(Context.User.Identity.Name, String.Empty)) Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("Validation of " & "Anti-XSRF token failed.")
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

No need to address this

```
Page.PreLoad += master_Page_PreLoad;
```